# Unrecognized escape sequence error in named SQL sequence's connection string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, connection, connection-string

Using Visual Studio 2015 ans SQL Server 2014.

I have tried everything from using '[]', using double back slash and '@' still it gives unrecognized escape sequence error. Any other solution?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Products(Id,Name,[Description],Price,IsAvailable) Values(@Id, @Name, @Description, @Price, @IsAvailable)", "Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: Even once you get the connection going the values don't look right.    Is @name supposed to be a parameter?   A string should be 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No constructor of SqlCommand takes a connection string once you figure out how to escape it correctly (with either the @ or \) like this:

```
var conn=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Products(Id,Name,[Description],Price,IsAvailable) Values(@Id, @Name, @Description, @Price, @IsAvailable)", conn);
```

or

```
var conn=new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Products(Id,Name,[Description],Price,IsAvailable) Values(@Id, @Name, @Description, @Price, @IsAvailable)", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the @ character with a leading @ on the string.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Products(Id,Name,[Description],Price,IsAvailable) Values(@Id, @Name, @Description, @Price)", yourConnection);
```

Comment: Refer to @Robert McKee's answer. You need to take the connection string out of the command. I didn't see that it was in there.